# Using postgresql functions to return date sensitive rows

Tags: postgresql, function, candlestick-chart

I am writing a function in postgresql to get candle information from a set of stock data I have. In order to draw the candles, I need to get the open, close, high and low values of a certain time period (say 1 day) so I would need the opening value of the day, the closing value of the day, the highest value of the day and lowest value of the day.

I have created a function in postgresql to get me a candle for a specific time period

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getcandle(
    starttime timestamp without time zone,
    endtime timestamp without time zone,
    psymbol character varying)
RETURNS candle AS
$BODY$
select
    startTime,
    (select value as open FROM "4" WHERE datetime >= startTime and symbol = pSymbol ORDER BY datetime ASC limit 1),
    (select value as close FROM "4" WHERE datetime <= endTime and symbol = pSymbol ORDER BY datetime DESC limit 1),
    (select max(value) as high FROM "4" WHERE datetime >= startTime and datetime <= endTime and symbol = pSymbol),
    (select min(value) as low FROM "4" WHERE datetime >= startTime and datetime <= endTime and symbol = pSymbol); $BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
```

And when I run this for a specific time I get something like this:

```
select * from getCandle('2015-06-26 08:30:00', '2015-06-26 08:35:00', 'AAPL')
start                |open  |close |high  |low
---------------------|------|------|------|------
"2015-06-26 08:30:00"|127.51|127.32|127.51|127.23
```

Now I want to write another function that selects all of the candles of a certain time period, I am calling this getCandles and here is what I have so far from lots of googling such.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getCandles(startTime timestamp, endTime timestamp, pSymbol varchar, candleWidth int) RETURNS SETOF candle as $$
declare
    numberOfCandles int;
    candles candle%rowtype;
    localStart timeStamp;
    localEnd timeStamp;
begin
    numberOfCandles := (SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (endTime - startTime))) / candleWidth;
    FOR i IN 1 .. numberOfCandles LOOP
        localStart := startTime + interval candleWidth * (i - 1) ' seconds';
        localEnd := startTime +  + interval candleWidth * i ' seconds';
        candles := getCandle(localStart, localEnd, pSymbol);
        return next candles;
    end loop;
return;
$$ language 'plpgsql';;
```

My biggest problem is that when I run that, I get this:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "*"
LINE 10:    localStart := startTime + interval candleWidth * (i - i) ...
                                                       ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "*"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 414
```

So my questions are as follows:

1) How do I use a for loop to to increment my timeframe by x seconds?

2) Am I adding rows to my candles variable correctly?

3) Is there a better way to do either of these?

Btw, I am taking all of this information and graphing it using a different program. I would rather not collect all of the information from post and send it to my program because I am collecting almost 10k records a day so if I was calculating candles for 7 days or a month, it would be a huge data request. It seemed better to write a set of functions that weeds out the data I need. Thank you so much, Stack has been an amazing resource and I don't know what I would do without it.

Comment: just for record - syntax for casting `type variable` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, here is my fixed function for those of you who run into this same problem.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getCandles(startTime timestamp, endTime timestamp, pSymbol varchar, candleWidth int) RETURNS SETOF candle as $$
declare
    numberOfCandles int;
    candles candle%rowtype;
    localStart timeStamp;
    localEnd timeStamp;
begin
    numberOfCandles := (SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (endTime - startTime))) / candleWidth;
    FOR i IN 1 .. numberOfCandles LOOP
        localStart := startTime + (candleWidth * (i - 1) * interval '1 second');
        localEnd := startTime + (candleWidth * i * interval '1 second');
        candles := getCandle(localStart, localEnd, pSymbol);
        return next candles;
    end loop;
return;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

My mistake was flipping the interval and the candleWidth.